# How to use aggregate counter in Spring XD

Tags: jira, spring-xd

I am trying to create a counter that would consider several options and I could turn to one of them and see the value. For example, in Jira, I get a log and calculate in the "processor" script added time to the task, then I create a listener on this field with "aggregate counter" with two parameters:

```
--nameExpression=#jsonPath(payload,'$.user.name') 

--incrementExpression=#jsonPath(payload,'$.changelog.items[*].computedTime')
```

and I can see the time spent by the developer to the task.
 But the fact is that I cannot view from the same counter other information, such as elapsed time on task several developers or spent time on this task of a single developer. Is it possible to implement this in Spring XD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a different counter (*i.e.* different counter name) per business need (*e.g.* named after the JIRA task, if I understood your request correctly)

So to achieve what you describe, you'd need 3 counter "families":

- one named after the username
- one named after the task
- one named after the username AND the task